# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)upgrade query?

Tags: 2010, sql-server

Will SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 be compatible for an upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 CU2 from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)?

If we upgrade(from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)) Is there any problem in SharePoint sites and farm level

FYI :

1. Operating System : Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1
2. SQL Server Version:  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)

Answer (score 1):

There are no breaking changes to the way SQL Server 2008 R2 works from RTM to SP2, there are many feature improvements and bug fixes to the SQL Server database engine (as well as Reporting Services, Integration Services and Analysis Services) but nothing that adversely affects the operation of an already healthy SharePoint installation.

It is safe (and highly recommended) to upgrade your SQL environment to 2008 R2 SP2 as soon as possible, as Microsoft may no longer support a SharePoint environment with the RTM of 2008 R2.

Comment: Thanks James. My farm is SharePoint 2010 SP1 . In this case, Is there any problem in sharepoint site level/farm level if upgrade Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) SP2.CU2 from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM). Please clarify my quey